# Move history from git repo to subtree

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on Github in which I intended to include a second Github repo (also mine) as a subtree. Unfortunately my inexperience means this failed so all the work I've committed since January has gone into the history of the main repo.

How can I copy this history into the second repo then change the main project to use it as a subtree?

Edit: One of the comments (now deleted) asked why I didn't just use a single repo. The main repo is private but the [second repo](https://github.com/parsley72/SlmInterface) is public - I'm trying to share what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed me to [Moving files from one git repository to another, preserving history](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/). The filter-branch instruction didn't work for me, possibly because my repo has no branches? Anyway, what I did was:

```
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> --
```

This gave me a repo that only had the changes in the subdirectory. I then merged this into my second repo:

```
git clone <git repository B url>
cd <git repository B directory>
git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
git pull repo-A-branch master
git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

I then used filter branch to remove the subdirectory from the main repo:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf <bad subdirectory>' --prune-empty HEAD
```

Finally I followed [The power of Git subtree](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/) to add the updated second repo to the first as a subtree.